# Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04 + win 10 directly boots windows, doesnt give option of dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu alongside win 10. It worked after installation, but when I restarted, laptop directly started in windows. So I installed again. This time the Ubuntu was showing while installation. I deleted that. And my mistake was the swap size I made 80000 MB instead of 8000 MB ( My RAM is 4GB). So second time I also tried to delet swap but couldnt delet that. So i created new swap of 8000 MB.
Now even after booting second time it directly booted in win10. So i searched for this issue and did following steps:

1. bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path EFIubuntugrubx64.efi
2. Disabled Fast boot in windows.

This didnt help.
So I restarted and hit Esc key while restsrting and with thisd it gave me option to boot into either Ubuntu or windows. So I started Ubuntu and gave the command sudo update-grub
Even after this restart gave only win10 and not Ubuntu.
Also, while installing Ubuntu, right at the beginning some error messages flashed which was very fast so couldnt see what it was.
With hitting Esc key, I get follwoing screen. [Dual-boot option with Esc key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YFPf.jpg)

Comment: Try this link [How To Install Ubuntu Along With Windows](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-dual-boot-mode-windows/) . It will assist you to the correct path.

Comment: What brand/model system? Some like HP, do not seem to accept the boot order change using efibootmgr that grub uses on install. Only the one time reboot works. Those systems often need UEFI update & then change of boot order from within UEFI settings menu, not UEFI boot screen. Or if alternating boots a lot, just use the UEFI boot menu key to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes I have HP. Would you please point me to some resourse? And as an alternative could I just use Esc key everytime I want to boot into Ubuntu? Will that affect in any way my work saved on Ubuntu? I can update BIOS but would need some directions on changing boot order from UEFI settings menu. Thank you in advance. And will this issue keep occuring in the future?

Comment: @kaviranga : I saw that article. I have followed exact same steps for installation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried change the boot order in BIOS?
Change Ubuntu into first order so that it will first enter Ubuntu grub.